# Is there any "remote console" for twisted server?

Tags: python, console, twisted

I am developing a twisted server. I need to control the memory usage. It is not a good idea to modify code, insert some memory logging command and restart the server. I think it is better to use a "remote console", so that I can type heapy command and see the response from the server directly. All I need is a remote console, I can build one by myself, but I don't like to rebuild a wheel. My question is: is there already any remote console for twisted?

Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`twisted.manhole.telnet` uses the deprecated module `twisted.protocols.telnet`. It is recommended to use `twisted.conch.manhole` instead.

Here are some tutorials of how to use it:

- [Writing a client with Twisted.Conch](http://twistedmatrix.com/projects/conch/documentation/howto/conch_client.html) -- twisted.conch documentation
- [Network programming with the Twisted framework, Part 4](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-twist4.html) -- IBM developerWorks
- [Twisted Network Programming Essentials - Chapter 10](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/0596100329/twistedadn-CHP-10) -- Online book preview

Comment: http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/browser/trunk/doc/conch/examples/demo_manhole.tac is also probably worth looking at.

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at `twisted.manhole`